# Positive definite kernels involving the $\min$ function

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, kernels

I am interested in the positive kernels of the form $k(x,y) = \min\{a(x,y), b(x,y)\}$ (assuming $k(x,y) = k(y,x)$). Some examples including $\min\{x,y\}$ and $\min\{f(x)g(y), f(y)g(x)\}$, but are there any other examples?

In particular, if $b(x,y):= a(y,x)$, are there conditions or examples such that $k(x,y)$ is a positive definite kernel?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

By the Polya criterion (see e.g. the [last paragraph on p. 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2437)), if $a\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is convex and vanishes at $\infty$ or $-\infty$, then the kernel defined by
$$k(x,y):=\min(a(x-y),a(y-x))$$
for real $x$ and $y$ will be positive definite.